# AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'clip'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I get the following error when I attempt to load a saved `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`

```
/shared/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MinMaxScaler from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.0. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
[2021-01-08 19:40:28,805 INFO train.py:1317 - main ] EXCEPTION WORKER 100: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/shared/core/simulate.py", line 129, in process_obs
    obs = scaler.transform(obs)
  File "/shared/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py", line 439, in transform
    if self.clip:
AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

I trained the scaler on one machine, saved it, and pushed it to a second machine where it was loaded and used to transform input.

```
# loading and transforming
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = joblib.load('scaler')
assert isinstance(scaler, MinMaxScaler)
data = scaler.transform(data)  # throws exception
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is you are training the scaler on a machine with an older verion of sklearn than the machine you're using to load the scaler.

Noitce the `UserWarning`

`UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MinMaxScaler from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.0. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. UserWarning)`

The solution is to fix the version mismatch. Either by upgrading one sklearn to `0.24.0` or downgrading to `0.23.2`

Answer (score 5):

New property `clip` was added to `MinMaxScaler` in later version (since 0.24).

```
# loading and transforming
import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = joblib.load('scaler')
assert isinstance(scaler, MinMaxScaler)
scaler.clip = False  # add this line
data = scaler.transform(data)  # throws exceptio
```

**Explanation:**

Becase `clip` is defined in `__init__` method it is part of `MinMaxScaler.__dict__`. When you try to create object from pickle `__setattr__` method is used to set all attributues, but `clip` was not used in older version therefore is missing in your new `MinMaxScale` instance. Simply add:

```
scaler.clip = False
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue with `pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2` in my conda or cmd. Essentially downgrading the scikit module helped.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that worked for me was to monkey-patch the `MinMaxScaler.__setstate__` to set this attribute manually to false if non-existent with the snippet below:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


original_minmax_setstate = MinMaxScaler.__setstate__

def __monkey_patch_minmax_setstate__(self, state: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    state.setdefault("clip", False)
    original_minmax_setstate(self, state)

MinMaxScaler.__setstate__ = __monkey_patch_minmax_setstate__


# Deserialize the scaler here
```

By adding this above the deserialization (unpickling), I managed to deserialize my object in a newer `scikit-learn` version and then re-serialize it with the `clip` alteration, no longer needing the monkey-patch afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

version issue of **sklearn** 
You need to install in windows 
`pip install scikit-learn==0.24.0` 
I solve my Problem using this command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).