# Having difficulty using hmni module in python. Installs fine, but errors out on simple commands. Looking for solutions

Tags: python

I am trying to do some fuzzy matching and want to use the hmni module for this.  I have installed the package using pip install.  When I import hmni in the python interpreter, I encounter no errors or warnings.  However, when I run the simple command:

matcher = hmni.Matcher(model='latin')

I get the following warning for multiple estimators:

```
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MaxAbsScaler from version 0.23.1 when using version 1.2.0. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
  warnings.warn(
```

The next simple command:

matcher.similarity('Alan', 'Al')

gives me this error:

AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'clip'

I have updated the sklearn module to the most recent version, but that did not fix the issue.  I do not know what else to do.  For what it's worth, I have no problems using fuzzywuzzy module.  Anyone have advice on how to solve my current predicament?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered the same error. Downgrading scikit-learn to 0.23.2 worked for me. `pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2`

Related error but not specific to the HMNI package. [AttributeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object has no attribute 'clip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635575/attributeerror-minmaxscaler-object-has-no-attribute-clip)